# Cannot access to wp-admin after moving WP site

Tags: wordpress

I manually moved my WordPress site to a new host and it is online. However, I cannot access to the WP Admin Board. I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/arestmco/public_html/wp-content/themes/socialite/framework/admin/layout/head.php on line 1

This is the head.php:

```
<?phpfunction theme_options_admin_enqueue() {       //CSS    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');    wp_enqueue_style('theme-colorpicker-css', THEME_HOME.'/framework/admin/layout/css/colorpicker.css', false, false, 'screen');    wp_enqueue_style('theme-css', THEME_HOME.'/framework/admin/layout/css/admin.css', false, false, 'screen');    wp_enqueue_style('iphone-checkboxes-css', THEME_HOME.'/framework/admin/layout/css/iphone-checkboxes.css', false, false, 'screen');      //JS    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable');    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');    wp_enqueue_script('range_input', THEME_HOME . '/framework/admin/layout/js/jquery.tools.min.js', array('jquery'), false );   wp_enqueue_script('theme_js', THEME_HOME . '/framework/admin/layout/js/admin.js', array('jquery'), false );    wp_enqueue_script('theme_colorpicker_script', THEME_HOME . '/framework/admin/layout/js/colorpicker.js', array('jquery'), false );    wp_enqueue_script('theme_eye_script', THEME_HOME . '/framework/admin/layout/js/eye.js', array('jquery'), false );    wp_enqueue_script('iphone_checkboxes_script', THEME_HOME . '/framework/admin/layout/js/iphone-style-checkboxes.js', array('jquery'), false );  }add_action('admin_init', 'theme_options_admin_enqueue');?>
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should not there be a space between <?php and function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is something related to the theme settings, /themes/socialite/framework/admin/layout/head.php

You can try to activate default theme in the database, or simply rename active theme via FTP, then try to login.